# What is USB BICR function in android?

Tags: settings, usb, stock-android

In the `build.prop` file I found an entry commented "Enable USB BICR function" (`ro.sys.usb.bicr`). I searched in Internet, but I did not find anything useful. Maybe you know?

Answer (score 0):

I found some hints in the [MediaTek (MTK) kernel sources](https://github.com/andr3jx/MTK6577/blob/master/system/vold/Bicr.cpp).

There is no description but with a bit of guessing it seems that this option allows you to present a virtual USB CD-ROM when connected via USB to a PC. Often this is used for providing specific drivers that are required for accessing special functionality of the device. The virtual CD is present on the Android device in form of a ISO-image.

From my understanding this option is only relevant for developers creating a custom ROM.